# I need to show $\exists$ $\alpha > 0$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $c$ such that $f(x) > \alpha$ $\forall$ $x \in (Q\cap D)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The assumption in this question is a function $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $c\in D$ and $f(c)>0$.

What I've done so far is, deriving from the definition of continuous, $\forall$
$\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ $\delta > 0$ such if $\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta$ with $x \in D$, then $\lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert < \epsilon$

Now, since we know $f(c)>0$, then $\frac{f(c)}{2} > 0$, so let $\epsilon = \frac{f(c)}{2}$

Furthermore, we see that,
$\lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert < \frac{f(c)}{2}$
$\Rightarrow$ $-\frac{f(c)}{2} < f(x) - f(c) < \frac{f(c)}{2}$
$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{f(c)}{2} < f(x) < \frac{3 f(c)}{2}$
$\Rightarrow$ $f(x) \in (\frac{f(c)}{2},\frac{3 f(c)}{2})$

Therefore I assume that is the neighborhood U??

I am not sure on how to continue from here

Comment: Is $D$ a subset of $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow down.

---

You define $\epsilon = \frac{f(c)}{2}$. That's fine. Now, you write

> We see that $|f(x)-f(c)|<\frac{f(c)}{2}$.

This is a very sloppy statement. What is $x$? How do we "see" that? For which values of $f$ does this hold? Without a clear understanding of the answers to these questions, the rest of your "proof" is meaningless.

So, let's improve it:

We define $\epsilon=\frac{f(c)}{2}$. Now, we *go back to the definition of continuity*!!!

By definition, there **exists some** $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(c)|<\frac{f(c)}{2}=\epsilon$

We can then, just like you did, conclude that if $|f(x)-f(c)|<\frac{f(c)}{2}$, then $$f(x)>\frac{f(c)}{2}$$

and this is very similar to what you want to prove, so clearly, we can set $\alpha>0$.

---

Now, again, we slow down, and look at what we currently proved. What we proved is the statement:

> If $\alpha=\frac{f(c)}{2}$, then for all $x\in D$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$, we have $f(x)>\alpha$

Does this sound similar to what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Let $U=\{x: |x-c|< \delta\}$ and $\alpha =f(c)/2$. You have shown that

$f(x) > \alpha$ for all $x \in U \cap D$.

So, you are done !